# Codeigniter decode function not returning value

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption

I have problem with decoding the encoded value after using `str_replace()`. It works perfect with encoding but when i try to decode it, it returns nothing. i have also configured the `$config['encryption_key']` but i am still facing this issue in codeigniter 3.x. please help me to get through this issue.

```
/*encoding*/
$tmp = $this->encrypt->encode($val);
$encoded_val = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$tmp); //removal of specific characters to eliminate uri segment issue
return $encoded_val;

/*decoding*/
$decoded_val = str_replace(array('-','_',''),array('+','/','='),$val);  //getting original encoded value    
$tmp =  $this->encrypt->decode($decoded_val);                    
return $tmp; 



//encryption key
$config['encryption_key'] = "someencryptionkey";
```

Comment: Its working perfect with the previous version ie, codeigniter 2.x

Comment: Stop using `CI_Encrypt`, it's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/encrypt.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code cannot work reliably: The only times you will be able to get the original value back, is when the encoded value does not contain any of the `-`, `_` or `=` characters.

If it does, your replacement will make it impossible to decode because when you do:

```
$decoded_val = str_replace(array('-','_',''),array('+','/','='),$val);
```

you will not get the value back that you had when you used `$this->encrypt->encode($val)`. For example all `-` characters will be converted to `+` characters, so if your original encoded value had any, now it will not.

And of course replacing an empty character with `=` does not really make any sense.

To be able to encode and decode reliably, don't do any character replacements after encoding / before decoding.

Comment: Thanks for the concern Mr.Jeroen, but if i am not using the character replacement, then it will a logical error when i tend to use URI segment. eg. http://example.com/module/QON6aMbk44VdkOukXjs_qcPkC1s7JfJYQf9Pd9LyOZcOAt5RqvETHnjMtKjMS9sFbR6xjDS4/q9KQ1kz8YRDmA

Comment: @kathirmalan If you want to use a string in a url, you need to encode it properly using for example `url_encode()` but that should not have anything to do with this.